# How to add custom text settings to a custom theme?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm working on a custom theme called "YingYang". I didn't make the theme, but I have to do some stuff with it. The theme has custom text settings which is bassically some pre-set content.

It looks like this
[image]

**Now my question is: How can I create a new text setting for this theme?**

I've been searching for a while in the drupal UI and in the code, but I can't find anything about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to give new text in this field or want to add a new textarea field..??

Comment: create a new option (add new textarea field)

Comment: You can use this manual http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-add-theme-settings-drupal-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now this option in your theme is in configuration setting. I think they done it using some custom module. Edit the module file, add a new text area using following code..

```
 $form['name']= array(
'#type' => 'textarea',
'#title' => t('Main Address'),
```

);

Save the

```
$form_state['values']['name']
```

using **variable_set('name' , value)** in form submit. Then retrieve variable in template using **variable_get('name')**.

Another easy method is just edit your theme-settings.php. Add a new textarea field. you will get the field in your **Home » Administration » Appearance » Settings**.
 You can access that value using

```
theme_get_setting('field name');
```

Hope this will helps you...